# MVC Pattern - Need to include services file or not?

Tags: node.js, mvc, express.js

I am refactoring an old project, made in Nodejs with Express, applying the MVC pattern, today it is a fairly simple project: handling of the FCM and Remote Config tools from Firebase.

Would it be helpful, or is it good practice, to add the services file to work together with the controller?

The FCM part would look like this:

Model - FCMMessage.js

```
class FCMMessage {
  constructor(title, body, topic) {
    this.title = title;
    this.body = body;
    this.topic = topic;
  }
};

module.exports = {FCMMessage};
```

Controller - messagingController.js

```
var FCMMessage = require("../models/FCMMessage");
var messagingService = require("../services/messagingService");

const messagingView = (req, res) => {
  res.render('messaging');
};


const sendMessageToTopic = (req, res) => {
  const {title, body} = req.body;
  // TODO: Remove hard code topic
  const topic = "all_users";
  const message = new FCMMessage(title, body, topic);

  messagingService
    .sendMessageToTopic(message)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("Successfully sent message to topic:", response);
      res.status(200).json({message: 'Message sent successfully'});
    })
   .catch((error) => {
      res.status(500).json({error: 'Failed to send message'});
   })
};

//...

module.exports = {messagingView, sendMessageToTopic};
```

Service - messagingService.js

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("../../placeholders/service-account.json");

admin.initializeApp({credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)});

const sendMessageToTopic = ({title, body, topic}) => {
  const message = {
    notification: {
      title,
      body,
    },
    topic,
  };

  return admin.messaging().send(message);
}

//...

module.exports = {sendMessageToTopic};
```

More route for the view and the posts router method:

```
var express = require("express")
var messagingController = require("../controllers/messagingController");

var router = express.Router();

router.get("/messaging", messagingController.messagingView);
router.post("/send-message-topic", messagingController.sendMessageToTopic);
//...

module.exports = router;
```

View - messaging.pug

```
doctype html
html
  head
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    title Messaging 
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="/stylesheets/style.css")
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:100,200,300,400")
  body
    form(id="msform" role="form" action="/send-message-topic" method="POST")
      fieldset
        h2.fs-title Messaging
        h3.fs-subtitle Manage messaging campaigns with the new unified campaign experience.
        input(type="text" name="title"  id="title" placeholder="Type your title" required)
        textarea(type="text" name="body" id="message" cols="30", rows="10" placeholder="Type your message" required)
        input.submit(type="submit", name="submit", placeholder="Submit")
        br 
        a.router(href="/translations") To remote config, manage translations.
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally fewer files, fewer places to maintain. I removed services folder and move Firebase admin sdk to the controller.